# Python logging strange behavior

Tags: python, ubuntu, logging, module, daemon

Consider this code:

```
ubuntu_logger = logging.getLogger('ubuntu-logger')

mail_handler = MailHandler()
mail_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ubuntu_logger.addHandler(mail_handler)

filepath = "/home/ubuntu/logs/central.log"
formatter = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s]: %(message)s')

central_handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(
    filename=filepath,
    mode="a+"
)
central_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
central_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
ubuntu_logger.addHandler(central_handler)
```

I create this handler in `serverutils.logutils`, a custom python module. Then, I import it into my daemon service script, which is run by `root` user:

```
from serverutils.logutils import ubuntu_logger as logger, DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG

logger.info('pydaemons launching...')
```

With the code above, the `ubuntu_logger` simply does nothing at all. After changing the code like below, `ubuntu_logger` works as expected, in addition to the root logger:

```
import logging
from serverutils.logutils import ubuntu_logger as logger, DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG

config = DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG # Fancy format, log level DEBUG
config.update(filename='/home/ubuntu/test.log')

logging.basicConfig(**config)

logging.error('omg, this works')
logger.info('pydaemons launching...')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to set a log level on `ubuntu_logger`:

```
ubuntu_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

otherwise it'll find the `WARNING` level set by default on the root logger instead. When you ran `logging.basicConfig()` you set the log level of the root logger to `DEBUG`, so the `ubuntu_logger` picked that up and no longer filtered your `INFO` level log messages.

What normally happens when you call one of the `logger.log()` helper functions (such as `logger.info()`) is that the logger checks if the current level allows for that message. If it's own level is `NOTSET` (the default), the parent log object is consulted, etc. until the root is found, where the default is `WARNING`.

You *may* want to disable log propagation if you have handlers set on a specific logger:

```
ubuntu_logger.propagate = False
```

otherwise the root logger is *also* asked to handle the log message. Propagation does not affect at what level a logger starts emitting messages.

Comment: I'll update the question, it seems I was looking in the wrong direction

Comment: @Mazyod: if you do, do remove the *EDIT* headers; we can all see the edit history, no need to make it a running commentary in the question itself. :-)

Comment: @Mazyod; updated; you never set a log level of `ubuntu_logger`.

Comment: I can't believe this... I thought setting the log level on the handlers was sufficient. Thanks for the extra details, they're really useful.